# Reverse parsing edi 835 file (FROM EXCEL TO EDI 835 file )

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, edi

Are there any python Packages to reverse parse an edi 835 file i.e, converting an excel data ( parsed edi835 file to an excel sheet) to an edi835 file.

Expecting a python Package that can convert excel sheet or a dataframe back to edi835 file.

Comment: Take a look at BOTS.  It's a Python translator.  Open source, you might be able to modify it to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen a Python library that converts an Excel file to EDI directly – you may consider looking for a Python library that converts Excel to JSON (e.g. [Dataknead](https://github.com/hay/dataknead), assuming that by Excel you mean CSV), and then another library that does JSON to EDI. I'm not aware of any Python libraries that do the latter – if you're open using a hosted service, [Stedi's EDI Translate API](https://www.stedi.com/docs/edi-translate/translate-json-to-x12-edi) would work well. There is a free tier.